# Virtual directory with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello i have the following page:

```
1st site folder: www.site.com /www/www1/
2nd site folder: www2.site.com /www/www2/
Ajax Folder: /www/ajax/
CDN Folder: /www/cdn/
```

the `www` and `www2` site uses some ajax stuff, since i dont want to create a own ajax folder to each site, i want to use the same directory, what i want to do is the following:

I have my `www` and `www2` sites, each one must use the same ajax folder, im trying to create a virtual folder to each one that connects to my ajax folder.

So must be `www.site.com/ajax/myfileajax.php?id=1`
Also for `www2.site.com/ajax/myfileajax.php?id=2`

Im trying with .htaccess but no luck only a 404 error

```
RewriteRule /inc/^(.*) ../ajax/$1 [L]
```

I don't want to recode all my javascript for x-domain ajax that's why i want to do this.
My hosting provider can't edit the httpd.conf so this is my only chance with .htaccess.
I tried `alias` too but don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this somewhere appropriate in the htaccess file in your document root (which I assume is /www/):

```
RewriteEngine On

# for www.site.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.site.com [NC]

# check that the request needs to be routed (ajax/cdn don't need to be routed)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# check that we get routed to an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/www1%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/www1%{REQUEST_URI} -d 

# Do the route to /www1/
RewriteRule !^/?www1 /www1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]


# for www2.site.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www2.site.com [NC]

# check that the request needs to be routed (ajax/cdn don't need to be routed)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# check that we get routed to an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/www2%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/www2%{REQUEST_URI} -d 

# Do the route to /www2/
RewriteRule !^/?www2 /www2%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The first check is to determine the hostname that the request is for. The second check is that the request isn't for an existing resource. If the request is for `/ajax/myfileajax.php` we don't need to do any routing if that file exists in the /ajax/ directory. The 3rd check is to make sure if we routed, we'd be pointing the URI to an existing resource. This bit is just so that 404 errors report the requested URI instead of the URI with a `/www1/` appended in front. In other words, don't route unless there's something there, otherwise let it just 404 like normal.

Comment: My document_root is /www/www1/ and /www/www2/

Comment: @EnriqueBenitez Then you can't use htaccess to write to URI's that are outside of the document root. You can just symlink `ajax` and `cdn` to both www1 and www2, and ensure `FollowSymLinks` option is on